# Can I use Airport if the network needs daily authentication?

Tags: airport

Each day, in my company, I need to manually login via a web portal:

1. Do a google request -> leads to nowhere
2. Do the same request from HTTPS to HTTP
3. Be redirected to the login portal
4. Click login, an AUTH popup shows itself
5. Enter credentials.
6. Access to the web

Can the Airport Extreme be used in that condition? 
Will it ask to do the same step for the first user connecting to the Airport Extreme in the morning?

Or will we have to each day, reconfigure the airport manually?

Thanks

Comment: Airport is used for a unix command line tool, to brand Apple's networking hardware of various generations and options. What specifically is "airport" and what does "used" look like? What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: "User connecting to the airport." He means an AP. It seems pretty clear to me. He's asking about the Airport Extreme, or Express (probably Extreme though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Airport line of devices do not support captive portals, if that's what you're referring to. There is no way to set one up to support this. That's more an enterprise feature, and wouldn't be found in most consumer APs.